# Preparation of Sodium Peroxoborate

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

> Write balanced equations for each step, and an overall equation, for the preparation of sodium peroxoborate hexahydrate from the reagents borax, $\ce{NaOH}$, and $\ce{H2O2}$.

Borax was added to a solution of $\ce{NaOH}$, then it was treated with $\ce{H2O2}$, then cooled to form a precipitate. Please help.

(No structures are necessary, simply the chemical formulas will suffice)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reaction of borax with NaOH](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/115146/reaction-of-borax-with-naoh)

Answer (score 3):

Sodium peroxoborate can be prepare using two methods.

1. Electrolysis of sodium borate with some sodium carbonate
2. Oxidation of sodium meta borate using $\ce{H2O2}$

Heating borax strongly will give a mixture of sodium meta borate and boric anhydride.

If you can remove boric anhydride from the transparent glass like mixture, you can then add $\ce{H2O2}$

$$\ce{2NaBO2 + 2H2O2 + 6H2O -> Na2[(OH)2B(O - O)2B(OH)2].6H2O}$$