# Balanced Chemical Equations of the preparation of sodium peroxoborate

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

I know the chemical equation for the reaction of borax with sodium hydroxide and hydrogen peroxide

$$\ce{Na_2[B_4O_5(OH)_4]\cdot6H_2O + 2NaOH + 4H_2O_2 ->2Na_2[B_2(O_2)_2(OH)_4]\cdot6H_2O + 3H_2O} $$

Now when we were doing the experiment to prepare sodium peroxoborate we added, the $\ce{NaOH}$ first and then $\ce{H_2O_2}$. How do I write the chemical equations for the borax with just the sodium hydroxide and then that product with the hydrogen peroxide. Essentially how do I break the balanced chemical equation that I have into two different steps.

Comment: Strongly related: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/44911/preparation-of-sodium-peroxoborate-equations/44913

Comment: It doesn't answer my question at all. I already have that equation posted by Aditya Dev